# How create a pyspark dataframe with sum of columns from different dataframes?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have two tables **DF1**, **DF2** and I need create an **DF3** with the same columns (all columns are the same) but the value of each needs to be the sum of respective columns in the other dataframes, here is a little example, the real dfs have 38 columns:

edit: id column is the only one that always be need the same value.

**DF1**

| id | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2 | 15 | 10 | 5 |

**DF2**

| id | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 10 | 15 |

**Expected DF3**

| id | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 22 | 33 |
| 2 | 20 | 20 | 20 |

I'm newbie working with pyspark and I had no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

union, groupby and agg the sum.

```
DF1.unionByName(DF2).groupby('id').agg(*[sum(x).alias(x) for x in ['val1','val2','val3']]).show()
```

Comment: if there are large number of columns, one could try the same with generalizing the comprehension -- `[sum(x).alias(x) for x in df1.columns if x != 'id']`

Comment: This solve the entiere problem, thanks a lot!